# My android app stop I don´t know how get a value of SQLite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm new programmer, I need just one value ("IdUser") of SQLite and parse to String variable, but I don't have any idea to catch it and return that value. My app stopped because of this.

Activity.java

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String LOGIN2 ="Users";
        String eti = loginDataBaseAdapter.CheckEtiqueta(LOGIN2);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), eti, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
```

UsersDatabaseHelper.java

```
    public String CheckEtiqueta(String LOGIN2) {

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+LOGIN2+" WHERE IdUser = 20 ORDER BY IdUser LIMIT1", null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
             //Sample operation with the Database
             if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"))!=null) { 
                   LOGIN2=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("IdUser"));
                   return LOGIN2;
             }
        }
        return LOGIN2;


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit you question to post the stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

First of all please correct your **SQL query.** and why you are returning the same variable that function received. You also havn't opened your database. 
To open database.

```
public void openDatabase()
    {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

And To close :

```
public void closeDatabase()
    {
        if (database != null && database.isOpen())
            database.close();
    }
```

Add `openDatabase()` call before Cursor statement and Don't forget to `closeDatabase()` once you done with it.

**EDIT :**

Ideal Code :

```
public User getUserByID(int userID)
    {
        openDatabase();
        Cursor userByID= database.rawQuery("select * from UsersTable where UserID = " + userID, null);

        User user = new User();

        userByID.moveToFirst();
        user.setName(userByID.getString(userByID.getColumnIndex("UserName")));

        userByID.close();

        closeDatabase();
        return User;
    }
```

Comment: In my DataBaseHelper I have the next classes:    public  UsersDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
  {
   context = _context;
   dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
  
  
  
  public  UsersDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
  {
   db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   return this;
  }
  
  public void close() 
  {
   db.close();
  }

  public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
  {
   return db;
  }

Comment: By the way I need just the value "IdUser" of Users Table (In my classes I close/open)

Comment: @GabrielDurruti I have made changes as per your req